# Backup in Sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 10 million of records in it.In it there is a column known as YEAR by which i can trace for which year the record is.Can it is possible to take Backup(.bak) of Only 2 years like 2010 & 2011 Only.

Answer (score 4):

If your table is partitioned via the `date` column, and you have allocated individual `filegroups` for each `Year` per partition, then you can use a [partial backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191539.aspx).  Otherwise, SQL Server doesn't have this capability.

If Partitioning is an option, here is a great [White Paper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/B/D/DBDE7972-1EB9-470A-BA18-58849DB3EB3B/PartTableAndIndexStrat.docx) about Partitioned Table and Index concepts.  Also, check out the MSDN article about [Creating Partitioned Tables and Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188730%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Some options would be:

- `bcp` the data out
- Insert the data into a new table, in a new database and then backup the new DB.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table table2(column1 varchar(50),column2 date)
```

---

```
insert into table2(column1,column2)
select column1,column2 from table1
where table1.column2='2010' or table1.column2='2011'

----------
```

now take the backup of this table

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. A backup will backup the full database, with all objects and data.

One option would be to create a new database, with 1 table, and write a script to INSERT into this. Then backup this new database.

```
INSERT INTO [NewDB].dbo.tbl (Value1, Value2, Year)
SELECT Value1, Value2, Year
FROM [OldDB].dbo.tbl
WHERE Year IN (2010, 2011)
```